# rake db:migrate fails when using devise_for on models that use class methods that hit the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My User model uses the column_names method to allow mass_assignment on all columns for admins.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible *column_names, as: :admin 

end
```

However, this doesn't play well with my route file that has devise configured

```
Sandbox::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
end
```

That is, when I want to create my users table via "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test". I get

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'sandbox_test.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users`
```

Full trace at http://pastie.org/3748502

I know the table doesnt exist, that's why I need to run my migration, but somehow, rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test reloads the routes, thus calling devise_for, and devise_for loads User class when adding the devise mapping, thus calling the column_names method on a table that doesn't exist yet.

So I'm not really sure how to cleanly handle this? Should I add add if table_exists? everytime I want to use column_names method? or is there a better way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to do this would be to list the attributes you want available to admins. Testing for table existence or doing something with rescue will likely obscure your intent.

Comment: I see. I'm gonna have to change that line though every time I add a new column